# How to map the mean over bootstrapped samples in a tidy data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to map a function that will calculate p_hat from the bootstrap samples I mapped previously in my data frame.  I am having difficulty with my function or my use of map, which I can say is a work in progress.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rsample)
ttSample <- data.frame(grad =  c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

bootstrapper <- function(n) {bootstraps(data = ttSample, times = n)}
meanTaker <- function(columnVal) 
{
  for(i in 1:length(columnVal)) 
  {
     meanHolder <- vector("double", nrow(columnVal[[i]]))
     for(j in 1:nrow(columnVal[[i]]))
     {
         meanHolder[[j]] <- mean(as.data.frame(columnVal$splits[[j]])$grad)
     }
   mean(meanHolder)
   }
}

 bootFrame <-  data.frame(n = rep(c(250, 1000, 5000, 10000), 3), 
    confLev = rep(c(0.9, 0.95, 0.99))) %>%
     arrange(n, confLev) %>%
     mutate(alpha = 1 - confLev,
       upperCI = confLev + (alpha / 2),
       lowerCI = confLev - (alpha / 2),
       samples = map(ttSample, list),
       boots = map(.x = .$n, .f = bootstrapper)) %>%
     mutate(p_hat = map(.x = .$boots, .f = meanTaker))
```

Comment: Try to give some more detail about what is going wrong and what you have tried.   For example do the boostrapper and meanTaker functions work as expected?

Comment: Sure.  Bootstrapped does work as expected.  The meanTaker not so much.  I was anticipating a single value p_hat for each row making 12 p_hat’s in one column called p_hat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that `map` applies the function to each element of the input, not the entire input.  Having that in mind, we can rewrite `meanTaker` as

```
meanTaker <- function(boot) {
    grads <- sapply(boot$splits, function (split) split$data$grad)
    mean(grads)
}
```

Comment: The reason for the double for loops (which I know I should learn to avoid, I’m just trying find something that works first before optimizing) is that each value in the ‘boots’ column is a ‘n’ bootstrapped samples of the list ‘ttSample’.  So, the goal of my map function is to find the mean of each bootstrap sample within each ‘boots’ cell and then take the total mean of the their means.  I believe this solution is just taking the mean of the first sample within each ‘boot’.